# How to make CSS drop down menu appear/change on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a web page, 1000px by 1000px for the main div. Inside the main div, at the top, there is a horizontal bar with four sections, each taking up 1/4 of the space. Each section has some text [wrapped in h2 tag], horizontally/vertically centered in the middle of the 1/4 section and each section must generate a drop-down menu.

For the drop down menu [which must work both on mobile and desktop], I borrowed the idea of using a checkbox [check for make dropdown visible, uncheck for invisible], but it isn't working correctly. The checkbox is small and if it is invisible it is almost impossible to know where to click to check/uncheck. I want the drop down menu to appear if the user clicks/taps ANYWHERE in the 1/4 section area.

The horizontal row of 1/4 section drop down menus looks like this:
[image: Row of drop down menus]

^ Note that they don't actually work.

HTML Code:

```
<div id="Media_Choices">
    <div id="Video" class="media_choice"> <h2>Video▼</h2> </div>
    <div id="Pictures" class="media_choice"> <h2>Pictures▼</h2> </div>
    <div id="Audio" class="media_choice"> <h2>Audio▼</h2> </div>
    <div id="Stories" class="media_choice"> <h2>Stories▼</h2> </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#Media_Choices {
    width: 100%;
    max-height:40px;
    min-height:40px;
}
.media_choice {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    width: 24.5%;
    max-height: 38px;
    min-height: 38px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 38px;       /* the same as your div height */
}
#Video {
}
#Pictures {
}
#Audio {
}
#Stories {
}
```

Extra credit if you can get the ▼ downward facing arrow to turn into a ▲ whenever the drop down menu is down and then revert back into a ▼ downward facing arrow whenever the menu is up. You don't need to use the check-box based technique [I know there is a hover option], but anything that works cross platform is good.

For reference, check boxes were origionally implemented using the following code [taken from another question], but copy-pasting in this solution and changing the text inside the box isn't good enough:

```
<input class="dropdowninput" type="checkbox" id="dropdownbox1"/>
<div class="dropdownbox">
    <label for="dropdownbox1">Open dropdown</label>
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li>...</li><li>etc</li>
    </ul>
</div>
with CSS:

.dropdowninput, .dropdown {display:none;}
.dropdowninput:checked + .dropdownbox .dropdown {display:block;}
```

Comment: Do you have a menu that works?

Comment: You say that you're using checkboxes, but your code does not reflect that.  Please show an attempt at using checkboxes so we can see where you're going wrong.

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: The way I did checkboxes was copy pasted off another question:

Comment: It's not opinion based, just make it so that you can click in the box to get the drop down. You guys are really anal.

Comment: @Paulie_D - changed the title to "How to make CSS drop down menu appear/change on click".

Comment: One thing I can't stand about this site is I just go here to get things done. You people have a way of delivering an onslought of criticism for the teeniest things. @Allicarn - It doesn't matter whether my attempt to make a drop-down menu involved hidden checkboxes or a :hover option. Neither of those things make any difference. In this case the solution was to use Javascript.

Comment: @AndrewBone - If I had a good, working drop-down menu, I wouldn't be posting here. I mean sure I can have a little box in the corner that you have to click on to make the drop down options appear, but that sucks and it isn't even relevant to the answer.

Comment: @MichaelLafayette the whole point of this site is to learn, not to "just get things done".  That is why we were all asking for clarifications and to see what you had attempted, so that we could help you learn.  No need to bite the hand that is (attempting) to feed you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand you correctly you want to create a responsive dropdown menu and you want the arrows to change when the menu appear/disappear, if this is the case a one way to do it would be to attach event listeners to the menu items that would show/hide the submenus on click, using css and javascript you can do the following:

```
.media_choice > h2:after {
    display: inline-block;
    content: '▼';
}
.media_choice.dropped > h2:after {
    content: '▲';
}
.media_choice > ul {
    display: none;
}
.media_choice.dropped > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

And with javascript add the event listeners:

```
$(document).ready (function()
{
    $('.media_choice').on ('click', function()
    {
        $(this).toggleClass ('dropped');
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arcm111/qdh7m8vu/)

Comment: This does EXACTLY what I wanted it to do. All I need to do is verify that this example works on Android browsers [chrome and also built in browser] and your solution is perfect. Thank you.

Comment: @MichaelLafayette you can do different animations to make it look nicer too https://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/jb6bwajh/

Answer (score 1):

Here it is using checkboxes and no JS.

```css
nav {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: none;
  /* to contain the floats */
}
nav li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
nav input {
  display: none;
}
nav label {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
nav label:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}
nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
}
nav a:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}
nav label:after {
  content: '▼';
  font-size: 10px;
}
nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
}
nav ul ul li {
  width: 100%;
  float: none;
}
nav input:checked ~ ul {
  display: block;
}
nav input:checked ~ label:after {
  content: '▲';
}
```

```html
<!-- http://codepen.io/allicarn/pen/gPPmZZ -->
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="navitem1" name="navinputs" />
      <label for="navitem1">Menu Item #1</label>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item #1a</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item #1b</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item #1c</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item #1d</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="navitem2" name="navinputs" />
      <label for="navitem2">Menu Item #2</label>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item #2a</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item #2b</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item #2c</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item #2d</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="navitem3" name="navinputs" />
      <label for="navitem3">Menu Item #3</label>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item #3a</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item #3b</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item #3c</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item #3d</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="navitem4" name="navinputs" />
      <label for="navitem4">Menu Item #4</label>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item #4a</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item #4b</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item #4c</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item #4d</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```